# Library files in C

Tags: c

Are library files `.o` or `.exe` files in C?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither; generally `.o` files are object files and `.exe` files are fully-linked binaries (on Windows).

- Static libraries in Linux are `.a`
- Dynamic libraries in Linux are `.so`
- Static libraries in Windows are `.lib`
- Dynamic libraries in Windows are `.dll`

Comment: there's also .la files which are typically used by libtool

Comment: Theres also the .lib libraries that come with a .dll that you use at compile-time but not runtime. I don't think that are technically static libraries - If I recall, they contain the positions of code in the DLL.

Answer (score 5):

It's more operating system dependent than language dependent.

- In Windows, they are likely to be .dll files.
- In Linux, they are likely to be .a or .so files.
- In OS X, they are likely to be .a, .so or .dylib files.

Answer (score 3):

Neither. It also depends on the platform. Also, the file extension is only convention and libraries can have any other or no extension at all.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is libraries are neither *.o or *.exe. Also the naming convention depends on the Platform you are compiling. 
A *.so file is a shared lib. *.a is a static library on the Linux platform.

You can specify options at compile time to build the libraries.

[Here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) you can check more about shared libraries and compilation and build options for the same.

Answer (score 1):

In linux, library files are an archive of one or more .o files.  Linux uses the 'ar' program ( think 'tar' without the tape ), to create the archive.  After bundling them together, you then use the ranlib program to add some indexing.

```
ar rc mylib.a source1.o source2.o source3.o
ranlib mylib.a
```